# Python Noob - Looking for anti-spaghetti suggestions and avoiding redundant code

Tags: python-3.x, function, validation, methods

First post here. I wanted to get this out to you folks because I'm looking for some insightful feedback and my approaches coming back into this world. My main experience is with Javascript on front-end work, and I hadn't written a single letter of python until yesterday afternoon, so excuse the mess.

I'm trying to see what you might see as some right-off-the-bat suggestions for abbreviating, or cleaning up this code. Maybe some glaring "please never do this again" items, or whatever insight you might have.

It's a console number guessing game, currently 1 - 10. It does run, with some bugs. The one main one that keeps tripping me up (and I'm sure it's simple) is if you guess the correct answer on the last try (3rd in this case) it does not run the 'Congrats' code. It runs the 'You failed' section.

Just looking for some suggestions or input of any kind to help assess MY thinking and approach to problem solving in this language. Also, if there's a better place on the web for this kind of nooby-ness, let me know. Thanks!

```
from random import randint


def guessing_game():
    # Set the count and limits for the loop and game length.
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 2
    # Ask the user to take a guess.
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
    # Randomize the answer. Change the range according to preference.
    the_answer = randint(1, 10)
    # Start the loop
    while guess_count < guess_limit:

        if guess == the_answer:  # The user wins and is prompted to play again. Init function would probably be useful.
            print(f"Congrats, you won! The answer is {the_answer}!")
            restart = input("Play again? ")
            if restart.upper() == "Y":
                guessing_game()
            else:  # The user declines to play and we break out of the loop.
                print("Okay, thanks for playing! ")
                break
            break
        elif guess != the_answer:  # The user guessed the wrong answer. Ask again and add to the count.
            print("Oops, try again.")
            guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
            guess_count += 1

        if guess_count == guess_limit:  # Shucks, the user failed. Inform them of their failure and offer redemption.
            print('Sorry, you failed.')
            restart = input("Play again? ")
            if restart.upper() == "Y":
                guess_count = 0
                guessing_game()
            else:  # The user opted out of continuing this exciting adventure.
                print("Okay, thanks for playing! ")
                break


guessing_game()
```

1/23/2020 - 12:45pm EST Notice the updated code below per @An0n1m1ty. With this updated code I can make up to 4 incorrect guesses before it terminates. On the second wrong guess, there is no 'Oops' message printed, and on the fourth wrong guess, the program just ends. No 'You lost' message or prompt to play again.

Winning, however, seems to be functioning correctly. I will go over it and try to identify the logic behind the current behavior. You can see the changes I made with comments starting with 'CHANGE'.

Also, if there's a better place to display these code updates, please let me know. I didn't put it in an answer, because it's not an answer. Sorry, I'm a noob.

```
from random import randint


def guessing_game():
    # Set the count and limits for the loop and game length.
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 2
    # CHANGE Moved guess input from here to beginning of loop
    # Randomize the answer. Change the range according to preference.
    the_answer = randint(1, 10)
    # Start the loop
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        # CHANGE Ask the user to take a guess.
        guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
        if guess == the_answer:  # The user wins and is prompted to play again. Init function would probably be useful.
            print(f"Congrats, you won! The answer is {the_answer}!")
            restart = input("Play again? ")
            if restart.upper() == "Y":
                guessing_game()
            else:  # The user declines to play and we break out of the loop.
                print("Okay, thanks for playing! ")
                break
            break
        elif guess != the_answer and guess_count != guess_limit:  # CHANGE The user guessed the wrong answer.
            print("Oops, try again.")
            guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
            guess_count += 1

        elif guess_count == guess_limit:  # CHANGE Shucks, the user failed. Inform them of their failure and offer redemption.
            print('Sorry, you failed.')
            restart = input("Play again? ")
            if restart.upper() == "Y":
                guess_count = 0
                guessing_game()
            else:  # The user opted out of continuing this exciting adventure.
                print("Okay, thanks for playing! ")
                break


guessing_game()
```

1/23/2020 - 7:45pm EST So with these changes we are a lot closer. The main issue is that if you get three wrong answers, the program just terminates. No failure message or prompt to play again. I believe this is because the loop condition is met after three tries, so the loop breaks and the

```
elif guess_count == guess_limit:
```

section never has a chance to run. I solved this issue by changing

```
while guess_count < guess_limit:
```

to

```
while guess_count <= guess_limit:
```

which allows the aforementioned section to run and prompt to play again. The only thing with this solution is that the loop runs one more time beyond the guess_limit because of the <= at the beginning of the loop. So you have to reduce the guess_limit by 1 of what you actually want.

The problem I'm having now is that if I go through a round and lose (only) and choose to play again, after losing or winning that next round and choosing NOT to continue, it will say "Okay, thanks for playing" and the game immediately starts over instead of terminating. So that's where I'm at now.

Thanks so much for all your help! Sounds weird, I'm sure, but it has me looking at it fresh again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is where the issue is:

```
elif guess != the_answer:  # The user guessed the wrong answer. Ask again and add to the count.
    print("Oops, try again.")
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
    guess_count += 1
```

When the user finally gets the answer right, the next bit of code will execute:

```
if guess_count == guess_limit:  # Shucks, the user failed. Inform them of their failure and offer redemption.
    print('Sorry, you failed.')
    restart = input("Play again? ")
    if restart.upper() == "Y":
        guess_count = 0
        guessing_game()
    else:  # The user opted out of continuing this exciting adventure.
        print("Okay, thanks for playing! ")
        break
```

Now, if the user is on the 3rd guess, `guess_count == guess_limit` will be `true` and the code will execute saying "Sorry, you failed"

To fix the issue, I did the following:
Move

```
guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
```

to the first line of the loop. i.e.:

```
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
```

Then, change:

```
elif guess != the_answer:
```

to

```
elif guess != the_answer and guess_count != guess_limit:
```

Then, change:

```
elif guess != the_answer and guess_count != guess_limit:  # CHANGE The user guessed the wrong answer.
    print("Oops, try again.")
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
    guess_count += 1
```

to

```
elif guess != the_answer and guess_count != guess_limit:  # CHANGE The user guessed the wrong answer.
    print("Oops, try again.")
    guess_count += 1
```

Then, change:

```
guess_limit = 2
```

to

```
guess_limit = 3
```

Finally, change:

```
if guess_count == guess_limit:
```

to

```
elif guess_count == guess_limit:
```

Comment: I updated the original question with the changes that I made. @An0n1m1ty

Comment: So sorry! forgot to mention ```guess_limit = 3```

Comment: AND delete ```guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))``` in ```elif guess != the_answer and guess_count != guess_limit:```

Comment: I updated my post again to reflect the changes. We're close, just this one bug remains.

Comment: @An0n1mity I accepted your answer since it was clear and helped me greatly. There is a bug in my code, but you got me through the main issue I posted about, which is great. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Manual `while` loops are almost always the wrong answer in Python. It's much simpler to do a `for` loop over a `range` that runs up to the number of times specified. In addition, Python `for` loops can take an `else` block that executes when the loop runs to completion, but *doesn't* execute if you `break` (or `return`, or an exception bubble out), making them ideal for "needle in a haystack" scenarios where the needle wasn't found (`while` loops can have `else` blocks as well, but `for` loops are the better option here). It also lets you move common code (code that executes whether they guessed correctly or not, in this case, the "new game" check) outside both `for` and `else`, so you either output one set of data within the loop and `break` to the common code, or the loop runs to completion, and the `else` block outputs a different message before the common code.

So you could could be dramatically simplified by using a `for`/`else` to:

```
from random import randint

def guessing_game():
    # Set the count and limits for the loop and game length.
    guess_limit = 2  # Allows up to two guesses
    # Randomize the answer. Change the range according to preference.
    the_answer = randint(1, 10)
    for guess_count in range(guess_limit):
        guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
        if guess == the_answer:
            print(f"Congrats, you won! The answer is {the_answer}!")
            break  # Go to common code for retry
        elif guess_count != guess_limit:  # Don't need to retest guess != the_answer; this is an else that never executes unless they weren't equal 
            print("Oops, try again.")
            # Don't need to prompt for input again, we'll prompt at top of loop
    else:
        # Only prints if loop ran to completion without breaking
        print('Sorry, you failed.')

    # Common code run for both success and failure:
    restart = input("Play again? ")
    if restart.upper() == "Y":
        guessing_game()
    else:
        print("Okay, thanks for playing! ")

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Get in the habit of using the import guard now; it's not necessary yet, but when it is, you want to be in the habit
    guessing_game()
```

Note that the unbounded recursion here is potentially problematic. If the user plays close to a thousand times, you'll hit the Python recursion limit. If that's a concern, I'd refactor to separate "one game" from "all games", and have "all games" be implemented as a loop, so you don't need to recurse to play another game:

```
from random import randint

def play_one_game():
    # Set the count and limits for the loop and game length.
    guess_limit = 2  # Allows up to two guesses
    # Randomize the answer. Change the range according to preference.
    the_answer = randint(1, 10)
    for guess_count in range(guess_limit):
        guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
        if guess == the_answer:
            print(f"Congrats, you won! The answer is {the_answer}!")
            break  # Go to common code for retry
        elif guess_count != guess_limit:  # Don't need to retest guess != the_answer; this is an else that never executes unless they weren't equal 
            print("Oops, try again.")
            # Don't need to prompt for input again, we'll prompt at top of loop
    else:
        # Only prints if loop ran to completion without breaking
        print('Sorry, you failed.')

def guessing_game():
    keep_playing = True
    while keep_playing:
        play_one_game()
        # Common code run for both success and failure:
        keep_playing = input("Play again? ").upper() == "Y"
    print("Okay, thanks for playing! ")

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Get in the habit of using the import guard now; it's not necessary yet, but when it is, you want to be in the habit
    guessing_game()
```

This approach also helps minimize complexity; `guessing_game` used to do two barely related things:

1. Play a single instance of the game
2. Determine whether or not to play another game

Separating them out keeps the two behaviors separated, so understanding either feature is easier in isolation.

One last suggestion: There's no great way to handle the "don't give the Oops message on the last loop" case I can think of off-hand, but there are "not awful" ways to remove the need for a test that will fail on most loops. The simplest approach is to echo the extra message as part of the input, using an extra message that's initially empty, and unconditionally set to the "oops" message afterwards, so it's used for all subsequent loops. To do so, you'd just replace:

```
for guess_count in range(guess_limit):
    guess = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
```

with:

```
extra = ''  # No oops message the first time
for _ in range(guess_limit):  # Don't even name guess_count, we never use it; by convention, _ means unused variable
    guess = int(input(extra + "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10... "))
    extra = "Oops, try again.\n"  # From now on, oops incorporated into prompt
```

allowing you to completely remove:

```
    elif guess_count != guess_limit:
        print("Oops, try again.")
```

replacing a per loop conditional branch with unconditional execution paths (which also makes code easier to test, since there are fewer unused or lightly used paths).

Comment: Thank you for this thorough suggestion on a cleaner approach. It is very much appreciated! I will go through this a few more times and really digest it, then try to reproduce it (similarly at least) on my own to reinforce the concepts. I will make sure to up-vote after I get my reputation up :)